# Android w/o gapps. How to get purchased apps

Tags: google-play-store

I'm thinking of wiping Google from my Android phone using cyanogenmod w/o gapps using alternative app stores.

The problem is that i have puchased already numerous apps in Google play store, which I don't want to loose.

Is there a possibility to download and install manually the apps I bought at Google play? How to get the newest updates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there are 3rd-party sites that can do this, but you have to give them your Google Account credentials which is not a great choice.  I'm not sure exactly how they get the APKs after authenticating.  It might be better to use a site like APK Mirror to get new versions.  It depends on how the apps check their license status as well.

Comment: You could back up your purchased apps with titanium backup but there is no guarantee they will work without Google services and also you'd loose updates. What's the actual reason you wish to have android without Google apps?

Comment: Main reason are concerns about the privacy of my data. Seems that i have to decide if i want to take loosing some apps into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use this: [GooglePlayDownloader](http://codingteam.net/project/googleplaydownloader)

Though I had to edit the source code to get it to work for me.

You can browse the play store from your pc and also search for any updates to your apk's you have downloaded. I then adb install the apk's I downloaded.

I run it under linux but it is written in python so should be cross platform.

As said in your comments you use your google account but this software is local and not on a web server. Plus it is open source so you can trust in what your account is being used for.

You will need:

- Google Email
- Google Password
- Android ID
- Laguage Code (example: en_US)

---

You may also be interested in a project called [microG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-microg-gmscore-floss-play-services-t3217616). It mocks the gapps but doesn't actually provide any functionality.

Comment: Looks very promising. I'll try out. Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Ok. I could make it run with the "free crendentials", including searching for files. Additionally I could log in with my own account. (Got message from google, that new device was found). Anyhow searching with my account didn't work. Error msg: `File "googleplaydownloader.py", line 319, in search     results = self.playstore_api.search(search_string, nb_results=nb_results).bo
dy.doc AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute doc'' ` is this the same error you have fixed already?

Comment: Look at the forks of https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api/. The solution is in one of them, just can't remember which.

Comment: It has to do with your android ID not matching up with the user agent used in the script. You can actually use your google account with the default android ID "31130ef715df16f2", as that matches the user agent "Android-Finsky/6.7.13.E-all [0] 2920566 (api=3,versionCode=80671300,sdk=23,device=angler,hardware=angler,product=angler,build=MTC19T:user". Though it would be best to figure out the correct one for your android id.

Comment: Seems you are correct. I was using android-checkin to get my ID. In my first trys I have used the decimal value instead to the hex value of the ID in googleplay-api. Now I seach using my own android_ID. Anyhow, the search results seem to include only free downloads (which also is a usefull think). Anyhow the purchased apps don't appear in the list. Any idea?